# Could the tags autocomplete widget please show more than six options?

Tags: feature-request, autocomplete, tag-autocomplete

When specifying the tags when asking/editing a question, it seems that there is a constraint to show a maximum of six matches, which really is awfully unhelpful if you are trying to find the most relevant tag, and have no way of ascertaining which other tags contain your partial-match pattern, beyond the few that the site has selected.

Can this restriction be removed, so that we can scroll through all of the matches?

Or perhaps a "show all matches" link added, so that you can at least *ask* to see the rest, even if it's not the default behaviour?

Comment: What tag are you searching for a match on?  I get 50 matches when I to a tag search for `java`.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think he's talking about the tag selection area on the ask question page

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; yes, I am talking about the "ask/edit a question" form. I'll clarify above.

Comment: If nothing else, a link to a pre-filtered list on [`/tags`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) might be nice. I'm not sure that that page supports filtering except via the input there at the moment, though.

Comment: As it stands, this request is very theoretical. Can you give examples where this actually is an issue?

Comment: Well it's an issue every time you type something for which you suspect there *might* be an existing tag, and the resulting options don't include anything relevant. You can't tell whether the reason it didn't show up was because it didn't exist, or because some algorithm omitted it. If you could see the whole list, you would *know* whether or not something existed.

Comment: FWIW, the particular example which led me to post this (but there have been several other instances in the past) was attempting to select a tag for keyboard macros on an Emacs question, a term which I knew might well not go by that exact phrase as a more general-purpose concept. Using the /tags interface I can see that there are 14 hits for "macro", 20 for "keyboard", and 50 for "key". Maybe I could narrow it down by using multiple different search terms to convince myself that nothing relevant existed, but compared to *one* search and a scrolling results list, it seems a bit rubbish.

Comment: @balpha four and half years later, is this still "very theoretical"?